# Group alternate records in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to generate a sequence number for alternate records in Redshift

**Input Table**

```
| id   | previousid | idtype | timestamp          |
|----- |------------|--------|--------------------|
| aaaa |            | INPUT  | 2020-07-03 9:09:23 |
| bbbb | aaaa       | OUTPUT | 2020-07-03 9:09:23 |
| cccc | bbbb       | INPUT  | 2020-07-03 9:09:24 |
| dddd | cccc       | OUTPUT | 2020-07-03 9:09:24 |
| ffff | eeee       | OUTPUT | 2020-07-03 9:09:25 |
| eeee | dddd       | INPUT  | 2020-07-03 9:09:25 |
| hhhh | gggg       | OUTPUT | 2020-07-03 9:09:25 |
| gggg | ffff       | INPUT  | 2020-07-03 9:09:25 |
```

**Desired Output**

```
| id   | previousid    | idtype | timestamp          | GroupNo |
|------|---------------|--------|--------------------|---------|
| aaaa |               | INPUT  | 2020-07-03 9:09:23 | 0       |
| bbbb | aaaa          | OUTPUT | 2020-07-03 9:09:23 | 0       |
| cccc | bbbb          | INPUT  | 2020-07-03 9:09:24 | 1       |
| dddd | cccc          | OUTPUT | 2O2O-07-03 9:09:24 | 1       |
| eeee | dddd          | INPUT  | 2020-07-03 9:09:25 | 2       |
| ffff | eeee          | OUTPUT | 2020-07-03 9:09:25 | 2       |
| gggg | ffff          | INPUT  | 2020-07-03 9:09:25 | 3       |
| hhhh | gggg          | OUTPUT | 2020-07-03 9:09:25 | 3       |
```

**What I'm doing now**

I am currently doing a 
`row_number() over (partition by eventtype order by timestamp desc) as GroupNo` 
for generating the GroupNo attribute.

**Problem with current solution**

Because, the timestamp field is not unique, I shouldn't order on this field.

**What I want to do**

1. I want to generate the row numbers on the basis of previousid.
2. I want to check if every input event has a related output event.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (1) Your question would really be much simpler to follow if you replaced the GUIDs with simple codes.  (2) Redshift doesn't support recursive CTEs or hierarchical queries, so I suspect that you cannot do what you want.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your suggestion. I have made the required edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your process can be completed in Redshift using "sql sessionization" techniques.

Essentially you use a number of LAG() statements to compare the data over your specific windows and then compare the results to complete the final classification.

- https://sonra.io/2017/08/14/redshifts-window-functions-advanced-use-case-sessionization/
- https://www.dataiku.com/learn/guide/code/reshaping_data/sessionization.html
- https://blog.modeanalytics.com/finding-user-sessions-sql/